# I am tryng to write a website form filling automation script in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

When i run this code there are no errors but it doesnt do what i want it to do because i am supposed to receive an email if everything goes right.

I tried using mechanize but it always shows that the field name i specified doesnt exist on a website which is not a case with requests

```
import requests

url = 'https://silo-airsoft.com/giveaway/'
payload = {'ne':'sergejgolac@gmail.com'}
r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
```

I am doing all of this on a Terminal if it means anything

Comment: working fine for me `r.status_code=200` for me

Comment: I wouldn't recommend automating entry to a giveaway..

Comment: @CMMCD can you explain why?

Comment: @Alderven When the people running the giveaway see the same IP has entered multiple times they will likely disqualify all of those entries. And since the user is new to python it is not unlikely they will just do a `while True:` to keep submitting, I'm sure the owners would not appreciate this and depending on the users ISP it may be against their policy as well. At the very least it is unethical to submit multiple times when honest users would only get one entry.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you mean to do this

```
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Passing `params` means that your payload will be in get parameters, so you basically do `POST` to `https://silo-airsoft.com/giveaway/?ne=sergejgolac@gmail.com` with no payload

I assume you want to send request to `https://silo-airsoft.com/giveaway/` with 
`{'ne':'sergejgolac@gmail.com'}`

Comment: Still nothing. It just runs but I dont receive an email.Maybe the URL i am posting to is wrong? I am only 12 so ignore my lack of knowledge :)